# GetId() on two different Ids

Tags: java, dao

My problem is that I can't insert two different ids in my database. uhrid is always the same as kundeid.

I know that the problem is at the entity.getId in my dao class.

```
public Bestellung insert(Bestellung entity) throws DbException {
            if (!this.hasConnection()) 
                throw new DbException("No connection to Database");

            try {
                // create sql command with placeholder
                String sql = "INSERT INTO " + this.tableName + " VALUES (NULL,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);

                preparedStatement.setInt(1, entity.getId());
                preparedStatement.setInt(2, entity.getId());

                int affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                if (affectedRows != 1) 
                    throw new SQLException("Insert failed");
                entity.setId(this.getLastAutoincrementId(preparedStatement));           
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new DbException("Could not insert the entity=" + entity.toString(), e);
            }

            // return entity
            return entity;
        }
```

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createBestellung(
            @FormParam("uhrid") int uhrid,
            @FormParam("kundeid") int kundeid
            ) {
        System.out.println("BestellungService - createBestellung");

            Bestellung entity = new Bestellung();
            entity.setId(uhrid);
            entity.setId(kundeid);

            ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = null;
            DbConnection conn = null;
        try {

                conn = DbConnection.getInstance();
            BestellungDao dao = new BestellungDao(conn);

            entity = dao.insert(entity);

            System.out.println("Inserted entity: " + entity.toString());
            responseBuilder = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(entity);

        } catch (DbException | SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            ServiceException se = new ServiceException("Fehler aufgetreten", e);
            responseBuilder = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(se.toJSON());
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }

        return responseBuilder.build();
}}
```

```
public class Oberklasse {

    protected int id;

    public Oberklasse() {
        this.id = 0;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Oberklasse [id=" + id + "]";
    }
```

```
public class Kunde extends Oberklasse{

    private String anrede;
    private String vorname;
    private String nachname;
    private String adresse;

    ...

}
```

The class Uhr looks nearly the same.

Output in database:

```
id | uhrid | kundeid 
---+-------+---------    
 1 |   3   |    3
```

Expected output for example:

```
id | uhrid | kundeid 
---+-------+---------    
 1 |   2   |   3
```

uhrid is always the same as kundeid.

I hope somebody can help me with my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you think `entity.setId(uhrid); entity.setId(kundeid);` does? How would you possibly store two different integer IDs in a unique property of type int?

Comment: You need a separate variable for 2 values. You can't save 2 values in one `id` variable.

Comment: What does your `Bestellung` class look like? Does it have more than one ID?

Comment: Bestellung also get the edit from Oberklasse

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz is there no other way?

Comment: @LennartGaiser you need to create two variables that can store the value of `uhrid` and `kundeid` respectively. They can't be stored in a single variable at a time.